# Lucida OpenType - how to find out if font contains a glyph (blackboard 1)?

Tags: fonts, opentype

I am deliberating whether I should buy TUGs [Lucida OpenType](http://www.tug.org/store/lucida/opentype.html), but I am not sure if it contains all the glyphs I want/need. How can I find those?

In particular, I want to have a blackboard one, as in `\mathbb{1}` (or `\mathbbm{1}` from the `bbm` package). I have found this [character grid of LucidaNewMathArrows](http://www.dessci.com/en/support/mathtype/tech/encodings/lnmarr.htm), but it does not show a blackboard style one.

Also, how would I find out if Lucida OpenType contains `\hbar` or upright greek letters for mathmode (coincidentally, I found this in this[TUG-board article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-2/tb101vieth.pdf), but I would like to know how to approach this problem in general)?

Comment: Tex.sx might be just the right place for your question; a number of the people mentioned at the bottom of the site you're linking to are actually active members here: [Khaled Hosny](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/729/khaled-hosny), [Taco Hoekwater](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89/taco-hoekwater), [Will Robertson](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/179/will-robertson) and [Barbara Beeton](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton). Generally, I would've said: Contact the maintainer; but in this case, your request here might be sufficient.

Comment: Yeah, you are right about contacting the maintainers. But I thought this question might be of general interest, because Lucida is bound to become more popular (I guess) and I bet there are some people here using it. :)

Comment: As long as you don't have the font files I think there is no other way than contacting the maintainers/suppliers. If you have the files you could just try, use FontForge or `otfinfo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of queries are better directed to lucida [mailing list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/lucida). But to answer your questions, there is no blackboard digits right now, but `\hbar` and upright Greek exist.